# My SSMS does't see the directory with db files

Tags: sql-server, ssms, windows

I did nothing and my SSMS does not see db directories with files.

[image: there is my paths with files]

When I'm trying attach db ssmms can't find this way. But when  I create db the files put there

[image]

As I understood there is the problem with files permissions in windows. Checkboxes with permissions are grey and I can't enable ones

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running SSMS as an administrator?

Comment: Yeah, Ssms was ran as an administrator